# How to make webpage appear in site.pages array in Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll

I have a repository powered by Jekyll on Github and added some extra pages and want to include them into sitemap. This extra pages are located in project repository:

https://github.com/theasder/theasder.github.io

How do I make webpage appear in site.pages array in Jekyll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pages are missing the required YAML front-matter (http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).

For example, your wiki.html page, at the very least, will need

```
---
title: Wiki
---

<!-- Begin already existing code here... -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Once the YAML front-matter is added, you should see them show up anywhere you call site.pages